# Is it safe to keep uranium ore in my house?

Tags: radiation, estimation, radioactivity, biology, laboratory-safety

I bought 5.6 gr of uranium ore.
The measured gamma radiation is 1µSv/h, we didn't have the instruments to measure alpha/beta radiation.

EDIT:
The gamma radiation was measured at 1cm distance. I also updated the unit of measurement as I had only written 1µSv instead of 1µSv/h.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/118691/discussion-on-question-by-gello-is-it-safe-to-keep-uranium-ore-in-my-house).

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Assuming the measurement is 1µSv per hour, looking at [XKCD's handy radiation chart](https://xkcd.com/radiation/) suggests that it is equivalent to eating 10 bananas or having an arm X-ray. If you were staying around the ore it would be equivalent to living in a place like the Colorado plateau with higher than normal background radiation. So that is not much of a problem.

What would worry me more is the alpha and beta radiation. Alpha is short-range, so as long as you don't eat, inject or inhale the ore things are fine. The beta radiation might be more damaging, but [as this answer shows](https://www.mindat.org/article.php/918/Estimating+the+beta+radiation+dose+rate+from+uranium+minerals), the risk is pretty minuscule even for more active samples than yours. Finally, there is the issue of radon production. This again seems to be a microscopic factor, although sleeping in the same room as the ore might be unnecessary. See also [this page](https://www.wise-uranium.org/rup.html) for way more information than you need.

Overall, the ore is as safe as any other heavy metal ore.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your comparison. The equivalent would be 10 bananas *per hour* or one arm X-ray *per hour*, right?

Comment: @EricDuminil 10 bananas per hour *will* make you sick.

Comment: Note that eating bananas doesn't actually increase your radiation dose (or at least by much much less than you'd naively expect) - your body maintains a fairly constant amount of potassium by excretion, and bananas have the same isotope ratio of potassium as the stuff that's already in you, so there's no significant increase in the amount of K-40 in your body

Comment: 10 bananas per hour will make you sick even without considering radiation though.

Comment: 1µSv per hour for a year is 8766µSv or 8.766mSv (averaging in leap years). This might sound like a lot but the lowest one year dose clearly linked to increased cancer risk is 100mSv.  It's just over twice your normal background radiation (4mSv). Might be safe in a drawer away from where you sleep but I wouldn't recommend wearing it as jewelry. Well, unless you gold plated it. Gold makes a good radiation shield.

Comment: Also worth noting that uranium ore emanates radon. Probably not at sufficient rate to matter, but impossible to determine given the lack of information in the question

Comment: @henning--reinstateMonica True, but sloppy abuse of radiation dose and intensity terminology is like electricity in that it behoves us to educate people on the difference between watts and watt-hours because so many seem to get it wrong.  Especially on physics.SE we should aspire to some standard...

Comment: If you're worried about radon, doesn't "keep it in a jar" address that? (not perfectly, but enough for practical purposes)

Comment: @fectin not sure I'd keep a jar of Radon in the house where some kid could open it.

Answer (score 48):

With a half-life of 4 billion years, uranium is only very weakly radioactive. In fact, since uranium is a heavy metal, its chemical toxicity is actually more of a danger than its radioactivity. If you touch it directly with your hands, you should wash your hands afterwards. You should not eat it. Apart from that, it is not dangerous.

Regarding the legality:  Most countries have an exemption limit for activity below which the permit-free handling is possible.  For example in the EU, [Council Directive 2013/59/Euratom](https://eur-lex.europa.eu/legal-content/EN/ALL/?uri=CELEX%3A32013L0059) sets the limit for uranium to $10^4$Bq (including the activity of its daughter nuclides). The exemption limits correspond to the limit values of the International Atomic Energy Agency (IAEA).

Comment: The $4.5\text{ billion}$ is only for $U^{238}$ of course.

Comment: Put the ore (real ore, refined ore, isotope separated?) in a nice glass vial, and look at it. The glass will stop any alphas and betas. A few neutrons perhaps.

Comment: Upvoted for "You should not eat it". Of course also a great answer apart from that :)

Comment: Downvoted for “you should not eat it”. I took the advice to the heart, and instead dissolved my uranium ore in nitric acid to take it intravenously. I then died. Would not recommend, 
⭐★★★★.

Comment: Also, avoid perfluorinating it to UF6 and inhaling.

Comment: What Gert said. The (overall) half-life for U-235 is only 704 million years; its half-life for SF (spontaneous fission) is a rather more leisurely $3.5×10^{17}$ years.

Comment: @PM2Ring: In fact, U-235's spontaneous-fission half-life is actually _longer_ than that of U-238 - enough so that, even for highly-enriched uranium with upwards of 90% U-235, the majority of the spontaneous-fission neutrons are _still_ from U-238.

Comment: @leftaroundabout you'd have been better off making yellowcake. https://www.pillsbury.com/recipes/basic-yellow-cake/2b3266a9-647e-4ecf-bb1e-6620667b8cd2